# Flex TextInput: Show focused border even when not-editable

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am working on a Flex app that uses a `StageTextInput` which has `editable` set to `false`, but I want to manually show the blue border that always shows up when editable `TextInput`s are focused.
I can't find this anywhere in the skin code.

Is it possible to do this in Flex?

Comment: It's a 'state' that is made for selected editable boxes. I don't think there's a way to force it, you should write your own style for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the code in `SkinnableTextBase.as`, under `focusInHandler()`:

```
...
// the flag's old value.
var oldShowFocusIndicator:Boolean;

// Only editable text should have a focus ring.
if (enabled && editable && focusManager)
{
    oldShowFocusIndicator = focusManager.showFocusIndicator;
    focusManager.showFocusIndicator = true;
...
```

I needed to subclass TextInput (which is a subclass of SkinnableTextBase), and replace this with `if (enabled && focusManager)`.